# python module can be found using shell but not in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

When I do `import numpy` on my shell, `numpy` is found (I can use it). However, when I `workon` my virtualenv `import numpy` gives me `no module named numpy` error.

I tried to `pip install numpy` while working on my virtualenv but I get a `could not create '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages'` error. I tried with `sudo` and it says that `Requirement already satisfied`.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` is installed globally in your system, so it's ok that `virtualenv`can not find it (unless you specified `--system-site-packages` option).

The problem with `pip install numpy` may come from the outdated `pip` and `virtualenv` combo. Check versions of your tools and try recreating it with [`virtualenv 1.11.6`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv/1.11.6) (which includes `pip 1.5.6`). If the problem persists, report the bug at [virtualenv tracker](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues).